# xml file download in jsp

Tags: jsp, href

I have prepared an XML string in jsp and I would like to let the user download the string in an XML file.

Is it possible to offer the user the download link using href (e.g. text.xml) without physically saving the xml file to the server?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Create a jsp page that creates an XML.
1. Set the content to XML.

```
<%@page contentType="application/xml" %>
```

2. Print the xml using:

   out.println(xml);

Where xml is:

```
String xml="<?xml version...";
```

Answer (score 0):

see if your file is there on Some Folder then you can easily Used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="XML Path" download>
 Download
</a>
</body>
```